# Angular 4 Form Control Removing Validation/Errors

Tags: angular

I have a form control that I am dynamically setting validators and removing validators. Which is fine, however -- all my form controls are marked as status invalid when I try to remove and set.

My code for removing:

```
this.answerControlArr[pvqQuestionId - 1].clearValidators();
this.answerControlArr[pvqQuestionId - 1].updateValueAndValidity();
```

My code for setting:

```
this.answerControlArr[pvqQuestionId - 1].setValidators(Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]));
this.answerControlArr[pvqQuestionId - 1].updateValueAndValidity();
```

When I print to the console, I see in the browser that the errors are still there and the status is marked as invalid? I have also tried using before setting validators:

```
this.answerControlArr[pvqQuestionId - 1].reset();
```

[image]